# How to extract part of a string batch

Tags: batch-file

I have -

```
D:/Folder/GitLab/ENO/win/abc1/def1/abc.java
```

I want to extract the data after the ENO, like shown:-

```
win/abc1/def1/abc.java
```

and eliminate all the contents before the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "curpath=D:\Folder\GitLab\ENO\win\abc.java"
set "eno="
set "newpath="

for %%A in ("%curpath:\=" "%") do (
    if defined eno set "newpath=!newpath!%%~A\"
    if /i "%%~A" == "ENO" set "eno=1"
)

if defined newpath set "newpath=%newpath:~0,-1%"

if defined newpath echo %newpath%
```

`curpath` is split by the `\` and double quotes each segment.
This is done by use of variable substitution.
See `set /?` about how variable substitution works.

The for loop iterates each segment.
Once the segment `ENO` is detected, then the variable `eno`
is defined so that following segments can be collected in
the variable `newpath`.

After the loop, the trailing `\` is removed and the result
is echoed.

The result is `win\abc.java`.

As your comment about `for /r`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%A in (.) do (
    set "curpath=%%A"
    call set "curpath=%%curpath:%cd%=%%"
    echo !curpath:~1!
)

exit /b
```

This removes the current directory from the path.
`call set` expands the variable and replaces `"%cd%"` with `""` with no quotes. The 1st character is expected a `\` so is removed.

Comment: It worked fine, can you please let me know what need to be added if instead of setting "curpath", it should come by iterating the current directory directory.

Comment: If replace `D:\Folder\GitLab` with `%cd%` then the same result can be expected. A quick method could also be done with `call set curpath=%%curpath:%cd%=%%` to remove the current directory and may need to trim any backslash though I need a source of usage to modify. Again view `set /?`.

Comment: sure I will be checking set /?, while I am doing " for /r %%a in (*)" and using set curpath=%%a,

Comment: Using a `for /r` like your doing can use modifiers for relative paths i.e. `%%nxa` will give the folder name, rather then the full path so that may be another way to achieve your goal. View `for /?` about modifiers. If you need more help, try editing the question with more detail so I can try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take the path (use `\` instead of `/`) split it by the last path and then echo last folder name `%%~nxi` and add a slash with file name `%%~nxa`

```
@echo off
set "mypath=D:\Folder\GitLab\ENO\win\abc.java"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%mypath%") do for %%i in ("%%a\..") do echo "%%~nxi\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: the "win" can also contain folder, so in that case the o/p need can be win/abc/akj/abc.java, so I want to get value after a particular string i.e ENO

Comment: ok, then your question is unclear. Do you specifically want to find a string with win in it? Please edit your question and clarify what you require.